# how to run same testcase in 2 different URL in selenium JAVA

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, testng

How do I run the same test case in 2 different URL which has same functionality

Comment: Welcome: have a look here for [how to ask](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/asking). You likely will get downvotes for [no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/) and [unclear](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion) to name two reasons. In general it would help if you provided insights in what you researched and tried yourself and where you got stuck. If it is purely a coding question: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) is a better place to ask.

Comment: Your question is not clear can you explain little more.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the test runner you are using - most of them provide a feature called **Data Provider**.

In JUnit, you would use [TNG/junit-dataprovider](https://github.com/TNG/junit-dataprovider):

```java
@DataProvider
public static Object[][] urlDataProvider() {
    return new Object[][] {
            "google.com",
            "facebook.com",
            /* ... */
    };
}

@Test
@UseDataProvider("urlDataProvider")
public void multipleURLs(String url) {
    driver.get(url)
}
```

TestNG has a similar feature. See [this blog post](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-parameters-data-provider/).